# Pause playback on a video.js player

Tags: jquery, html, video, video.js

I have a simple modal window with a video in it (using Video.js). I am opening it and closing it using jquery on click. I need the video to pause/stop if the user closes the window at any point. For some reason I can't get it to work. I have been searching for a while now and getting the same answers so it should be simple but something is causing it to not work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<a href="#" class="video1"></a>

<div class="modal" id="video1" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modalBg"></div>
    <div class="videoContainer">
        <div class="closeBtn"></div>
        <div class="video">
            <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="auto" height="auto" data-setup="{}">
                <source src="video/video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".closeBtn").click(function() {
            $(".modal").hide();
            $("#vid1").player().pause();
        });

        $(".video1").click(function() {
            $("#video1").show();
        });

        $('video').on('ended',function(){
            $(".modal").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have included all of the necessary video.js files in the head, don't think it's important to include those references here.

Comment: I can get it to work if I just use $("video").get(0).pause(); but not if I reference the specific video id. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out...

this works for pausing all videos:

```
$('video').each(function() {
    $(this).get(0).pause();
});
```

this works for playing a specific video:

```
$("#video1 video").get(0).play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Video.js replaces the original `video` element with a `div` that contains the player tech, poster element, controls etc. The player tech element within the player may be a video element, but can also be an object in the case that Flash fallback is used. In either case the tech element itself will not have the original `id`.

Your solution targets the new video element, but this only works where the HTML tech has been used. Instead, use video.js's api to pause the video:

```
$.each(videojs.players, function(index, player) {
  player.pause();
});
```

For a single video:

```
videojs('video1').pause();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#my-video")[0].player.pause();
```

Comment: When answering questions it is best to explain in more detail so that it can be more easily understood by other users of the site.